awesomewm on Xubuntu - subjective question about why autostarts are done in lua.rc
My window manager is currently working fine - this is more of a very basic theory question about why things are done the way they are, and how I could try and make use of that.
Please bear with me as some of this is abstract/conceptual and my vocabulary might not be precise enough.
==
I've always used Xfce in Ubuntu since seeing it be used in Puppy Linux. I remember (iirc) that earlier on it used to be possible in Xfce to make a simple auto-start script to just run a bunch of commands at login, very similar to Windows' old autoexec.bat. Or it might have been that there was a special folder and everything in that folder would run.
Some years ago, in Xubuntu I remember this was changed and I had to replace everything with systemd's format of: systemctl enable [MYSCRIPT].service
This was harder(for me)-to-understand and took (me) longer, but it had some security benefits and/or benefits to the development tradition.
==
Now approaching awesomewm for the first time, because it is (can be?) a tiling window manager supporting X11, I have (basic! subjective!) questions about the way (some users make it that) this window manager handles autostart:-
In an online tutorial at https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/guide-awesomewm-windows-manager/
autorun = true
autorunApps =
{
   "program1",
   "program2",
   "program3",
   "program4",
   "program5",
}
if autorun then
   for app = 1, #autorunApps do
       awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app])
   end
end

====

Why is it this way and not:-

awful.util.spawn("Program 1")
awful.util.spawn("Program 2")
awful.util.spawn("Program 3")... ?

And is there a name for the difference between these two lists. The first one is "structured" or organised?
==

Is it preferable to autostart things here or via systemd ? I suppose the .services might be being launched from a lower level (systemd being lower than the window manager) so there could be subtle differences, but I'm a simple user-case and just want to run some things when the computer turns on.

Is it that this is a good place to open some userspace programs, but complicated things like network managers should stay in systemd?
Or is it because awesomewm is used in lots of different distros and has to be agnostic about what other ways exist on a particular system for doing auto-starts?
On reflection I think this (elsewhere-advised and copy-pasted) way of doing it perhaps is too simple, since it is loading the programs every time awesomewm is reloaded and thus creating duplicates of them. That would be happening to me because reloading awesomewm doesn't close all the previously-opened instances. But that could potentially be solved persevering with rc.lua, and not going out to systemd... or xinitrc.
==

The line "autorun = true" looks like it might be doing other stuff in the background.

I suppose it might even be taking "everything listed below" and putting it into a systemd service. I wasn't able to google that or find it within the man page and documentation, so is the only way to try and open and read the source code?
The rest of the code is (to me, apparently) self-explanatory. It just makes it that any program listed as being an "autorun" program gets run.
But is it that the variable(?), or flag(?), "autorun" could be called anything without that mattering elsewhere to awesomewm or X11 or Ubuntu. Is that right? I mean instead of ""autorunapps=" and "if autorun then" it could just as well be "blobrunapps=" and "if blobrun then"
==

If I'm hopefully still making sense... is one reason for arranging the (productive) awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app]) lines in this structured way that it allows awesomewm to apply other user-specified logic to all of the listed autorun apps simultaneously?

If so, what sort of things might I attempt?
For example, if I wanted all the auto-run apps to open with a green border I could (try and) write the code for that once here, rather than appending it to each awful.util.spawn(autorunApps[app]) line ?
Or the problem I mentioned above: about this way duplicating instances of the programs. Somewhere in a script that runs when awesomewm is reloaded I could tell it things like "close all the autorun windows from before" or "if any autorun windows from before are still open, count them towards any new autorun commands next time"
But I wonder what else: are there some examples of easier things that I could try and do inside this structure to begin with, so that I can learn as I go?
==

Given my number of startup programs is going to be quite small, and the ways I ideally want them to behave will be quite different, might it be better to structure this as a startup block for each program? So e.g. Firefox checks how many instances there are; Terminals put themselves on another workspace with all their past commands saved into all of them; Thunar looks up what the last empty workspace is and puts itself there.

It strikes me that perhaps this autorun variable wouldn't correspond to any real (metaphysical/logical) characteristic these programs have in common.
====
Thanks for any advice on any aspect of this it is hugely appreciated
